# What is the best way to create light-weight PNG images?

Tags: image-format, image-quality

I want to create light weight PNG images with good quality. Can anyone suggest the best way...
Note: Need to use these PNG images in android app designing.

Comment: weight watchers?

Comment: make it 1px x 1px and choose a nice color. That should be nice and light weight and it will be a quality pixel.

Comment: @DA01 I'm not asking for smallest PNG image. While creating a png image how can I attain least size without affecting the  quality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From **how-to.wikia**:

> PNG files are lossless compressed bitmaped images. While they are
>   compressed, they can still attain large file sizes depending on the
>   type of image data saved. Similar to GIF files, they are best suited
>   for images with large areas of solid colours and defined boundaries
>   (such as logos). They also support transparencies and 24 or 32 bit
>   colour. Unlike JPG files, they are not suited for storing photographic
>   image data. A properly compressed JPG can be about 10% the size of a
>   PNG in this situation. As PNG files are lossless, most methods of
>   compressing them involve running additional algorithms that try to
>   optimize the compression techniques used. Some PNG compressors also
>   remove useless metadata.

Examples: [Pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) or [Tinypng](http://tinypng.org/)

So yes, there is a way to compress them and to reduce file size. Having said that, this is also the *first google result* which you should have checked out. Additionally, what they are being used for also has an influence on what format you should use. I suggest including that in the question.

Source: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_reduce_the_file_size_of_a_PNG_file

Addition: I have had good results with [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) when compressing may files in a folder structure. Please also note the warning for Xcode compression.

Comment: Thanks ! I need to use these PNG images in android game designing. Is there any other options rather than compressing the image ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Compressing and removing meta data is really all you can do other than actually making smaller images.

Comment: I mean that in photoshop or any other designing applications is there any option of reducing the image weight after designing and exporting it to PNG...?

Comment: Yes, by compressing it. See the products listed above.

Comment: Are you making mockups? Wire frames? Are you making graphics or trying to compress existing graphics for use in your own project?

Comment: @AaronLang I'm designing icons, particles and characters for developing an android game. To reduce the game size, the size of images and graphics should be less. So I'm asking for light weight PNG images.

Comment: One thing you can do is to see how much of your graphics can be saved in gray-scale. A lot of the time that is possible and can save some space.

Comment: @AaronLang Can u please explain in detail !! which grey-scale u are saying?

Comment: For instance, in Photoshop, simply click Image - Adjustments - Black and White. A screenshot of my desktop, saved as .png, goes from 318KB to 297KB - so 21KB just from color data alone.

Comment: A lot of textures can actually be done in black and white. I'm not sure what your specific graphics are, but take a look at this screenshot from Halo 3 (http://toktak247.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/halo3_1.jpg) The walls that surround the game map, the single largest repeating element (except maybe the sky) is black and white.

Comment: @AaronLang Thanks a lot !! So handling more grey levels in designs will help a lot in reducing graphic weight, right?

Comment: Pretty much. The more B&W you have, the less color info you have (and thus the smaller your images will be). Of course, don't use B&W when it's not appropriate, but a lot of the time you can skip colors without there being a noticeable impact on the aesthetics. A good trick is to view your graphics in Black and White (on a Mac you can turn on gray scale in the accessibility options, not sure what you can do on Windows).

Comment: You will get additional compression by converting to 8 bit color. This limits your color palette and if you can work with that, your images will be very lean.

Comment: I realize that. My update was more about batch processing maintaining folder structure. Shrinking one is not an issue (for me), but hundreds is.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the programs suggested by KMSTR, I've had excellent results with [PNGOUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNGOUT).

From the [PNGOUT tutorial](http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm):

> "PNGOUT is a tool which can optimize PNG files created by other programs. It can be run from the Windows Run dialog box or at the command prompt. PNGOUT can produce even smaller files than `pngcrush -brute` or `optipng -o7`"

There's also a Windows GUI version called [PNGOUTWin](http://www.ardfry.com/pngoutwin/) available, although it's shareware so you'll have to pay a few bucks for the full version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't create smaller files than those other two, pngcrush or optipng, they both use the same underlying algorithms for their compression techniques

Comment: @Adam: Actually, no, they don't. Pngcrush and optipng both use zlib for the compression, whereas pngout uses its own, slower but more efficient, compression routine. Anyway, I did a quick unscientific test to confirm this, starting with http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png scaled down to 320 x 240 px in the GIMP (57190 bytes). Both pngcrush (with or without -brute) and optipng (with -o3 or higher) produced identical output files of 57012 bytes each, while pngout compressed the image down to just 55533 bytes (as did using optipng and pngout in sequence).

Comment: interesting. good info

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try Photoshop, File> Save for Web & Devices...

Comment: Thank u @Herry, I am aware of this option, but how far it can help me in reducing the file size?

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan it all depends on the type of compression being used on the particular type of image. Every image will compress differently, and every compression tool will compress it differently. The best option is to use the tools above to see which compression works best on which image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac then try [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) (lossy PNG compressor) and [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) (improves compression further).

On Windows it'll be [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.org) and [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/).

Comment: Thx for ur reply but i use Win7...