# File size increases with resolution when exporting to PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, file-size, image-format

Whenever I am trying to increase the resolution of the logo I am exporting from Illustrator the file size gets increased automatically, I would like to know if I could increase the resolution while the file size remains the same.

[image: 72ppi=451px×451px]

[image: 300ppi=938px×938px]

Comment: You shouldn't have to increase the resolution on a vector, resolution only pertains to rasterized images. Depending on the intended application of the graphic (screen, print, etc.) I'd recommend saving your file in a vector format (AI, SVG, EPS) rather than a png as the question tag suggests.

Comment: are you asking if you can add resolution without increasing the perceived screen size or are asking about the size of the file in bytes on disk?

Comment: The answer is simply NO!

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the resolution is literally creating your image with more pixels. More pixels = more data = bigger file size. There is no way around that. You can of course compress raster images, but without compression there is no way to get around an increase in file size (if there was, compression wouldn't even be a thing).

Since you're working in Illustrator you may be better off using a vector format (in which case resolution isn't an issue). For more on that see:

- **[What web graphics formats to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41/52050)**

For more on compressing your raster image, see some of the many previous Q&As on image compression and file size:

- **[How to reduce image file size more?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/64390/52050)**
- **[What is the best way to create light-weight PNG images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11475/52050)**
- **[Tools for *lossy* PNG compression?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4475/52050)**