# Why the size of the file is so heavy

Tags: corel-draw, file-size

I have a single line text matter and the file size is 15.5Mb may i know the reason behind it. There is no image or no vector shape just a simple plane text. Why the file size is so heavy. [file size](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZVV96TF9hb1RkeXM)

[image]

Comment: Hi atek, welcome. May we know what file type you are saving (jpg, png, pdf, ...)? Also, people are understandably hesitant to click links posted in a question. Please explain what the link is and why you feel the need to add it. Also, please see if [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84094/41100) answers your question.

Comment: @PieBie sorry i forget to add the coreldraw type now its added

Comment: Never used Corel, but try resaving the file via 'Save as' and overwrite it again. This, in InDesign at least, will clean up the assets and significantly reduce file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color styles and symbols in the document file might cause large size issue.

[source](http://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x5/f/543/t/47527)

Answer (score -3):

Im sure it a tiff file. :p 
Dont worry it normal for a tiff file.