# From jpg to png with similar size

Tags: png, image-quality, jpg, image-format, compression

I have a jpg that it has 414 KB. For different reasons I need it to be png. I tried to export it to png and then it is 2.1 MB. Is there a way to export from jpg to png with similar size and similar quality?

More details: I tried with different images and the results are similar. I tried Photoshop and Gimp and the size where exactly the same.

I need to be png because these img upload to a php automatic page where all the img are png. To accept sometimes png and sometimes jpg I would need to change a lot of code.

In the examples I provide both img are 2000px x 1000px at 300dpi
The jpg is 143KB the png 629KB

[image]
[image]

Comment: Depending on the image your quality may actually be better with a smaller file size. Posting the image in question would go a long way

Comment: Please add more information (the "different reasons" for one) and the image.

Comment: @mayersdesign: I updated the question

Comment: The answer to the question will mostly be "What have the JPEG and PNG file formats been designed for?", are it is very likely already answered on this site. For example in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54549/why-do-people-use-jpg-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people use JPG images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54549/why-do-people-use-jpg-images)

Comment: You're trying to export from which software? Are you trying to programmatically convert from JPEG to PNG as you upload the images?

Comment: @Luciano: I tried from Inkscape, Illustrator and Photoshop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be talking more generally about *any* image rather than a specific image, the answer is generally no. The PNG and JPG formats work very differently and each is more appropriate for different kinds of images. Broadly speaking, JPG is more appropriate for images with a lot of varying detail (think photography) and PNG is more appropriate for simple images with solid blocks of color (think vector illustrations/cartoons or logos).

See [Why do people use JPG images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/54549/52050) and [What web graphics formats to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41/52050)

So if your image was an export of a 1 color vector logo, you'd likely get a smaller file with better quality (you'll obviously only see better quality vs a separate JPG export from the original; you won't get an *increase* in quality by converting a JPG to PNG)... but if your image is a landscape photograph you're going to see a massive increase in file size. And there's not a whole lot you can do about it.

There are tools available to optimize PNGs which will save you on file size, but don't expect anything like JPG file sizes on complex photographs. See for example: [What is the best way to create light-weight PNG images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11475/52050) and [Tools for *lossy* PNG compression?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4475/52050)